# Is it possible to SELECT either 1 or 2 columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if within MySQL itself (without PHP), can you create a condition that if true then SELECT 1,2 but if false then SELECT 1? Or something similar within the MySQL syntax that can accomplish the same effect?

Thanks.

Comment: A SQL query returns a fixed number of columns.  So, you cannot do what you want with a single query.

Comment: A little unclear on your intent. Do you want to only return 1 column of the result set in one case or both in the other? If so, always make your SQL return both and use your application code logic to only output what was necessary per the condition.

Comment: To be more specific, instead of doing doing if(value='something',something, NULL) can it return nothing at all, not even a NULL value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of a Stored Procedure there is no way to conditionally select a certain number of columns. The number of columns returned from any one SELECT statement is static. The best you could do is have two CASE statements, one that would return null in certain circumstances. Still two columns, but one would be superfluous based on your condition.

Comment: I had suspected this is the case since I have done quite a bit of research and didn't see any way to do it. I wanted to post this question to see if I may have missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am uncertain whether this is what you are looking for...But please have a look

```
SELECT CASE ("column_name")
WHEN "value1" THEN "result1"
WHEN "value2" THEN "result2"
...
[ELSE "resultN"]
END
FROM "table_name";
```

Please have a look [here](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html) or [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/1MS1120313-Understanding-Case-Expression-in-SQL-Server-with-Example.html) for detailed explanation of this keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll look into your answer (and links ) and see if it satisfies my issue.

Comment: After looking into your answer, we still end up with the same amount of returned select columns but of different values. But thanks.